# Detectar y destruir objetos que colisionan

Tags: python, python-3.x, game, pygame

**Este es el código:**

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint


ancho = 1280
alto = 720


class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.ImageS = pygame.image.load("sprites/disparo1.png")
        self.ImageSnake = pygame.image.load("sprites/cazador1 der.png") 


        self.rect = self.ImageSnake.get_rect()        
        self.rectS = self.ImageS.get_rect()

        self.rect.centerx = 80
        self.rect.centery = 80


        self.ShotList= []

        self.vel = 1
        self.velS = 5

        self.vidas = 3
        self.viviendo = True

        self.AS = False

    def draw(self, ventana):
        ventana.blit(self.ImageSnake, self.rect)

    def move(self):

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 

        if keys[K_DOWN]: 
           self.rect.y += self.vel 
           if self.rect.bottom > 720:
              self.rect.bottom = 720 

        if keys[K_UP]: 
           self.rect.y -= self.vel 
           if self.rect.top < 0:
              self.rect.top = 0  

        if keys[K_RIGHT]: 
           self.rect.x += self.vel
           if self.rect.right > 1280:
              self.rect.right = 1280     

        if keys[K_LEFT]: 
           self.rect.x -= self.vel 
           if self.rect.left < 0:
              self.rect.left = 0     

    def shoot(self, ventana):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 
        if keys[K_SPACE] and not self.AS:         
           self.AS = True                       
           self.rectS.right = self.rect.right + 10 
           self.rectS.top = self.rect.centery     
        if self.AS:                     
           self.rectS.left = self.rectS.left + self.velS         
           if self.rectS.right > 1280:    
              self.AS = False         

    def drawShoot(self, ventana):
        if self.AS:                      
           ventana.blit(self.ImageS, self.rectS)  
           ventana.blit(self.ImageSnake, self.rect)
           pygame.display.flip()

class zombieN1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.ImageEnemy1 = pygame.image.load("sprites/zombie1 izq.png")      
        self.rect = self.ImageEnemy1.get_rect()

        self.s = Snake()
        self.y = self.s.rect.top 
        self.x = randint(1016,1280)

        self.rect.top = self.y
        self.rect.right = self.x 


        self.vel = 1
        self.viviendo = True
        self.vidas = 1 

    def movement(self):
        self.rect.left = self.rect.left - self.vel



    def destroy(self):
        pass

    def draw(self, ventana):
        ventana.blit(self.ImageEnemy1, self.rect)





def Game():
pygame.init()
pygame.key.set_repeat(1,25) 

ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho, alto))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

Player = Snake()
Enemy1 = zombieN1()
BG = pygame.image.load("sprites/fondo.png")

InGame = True
ronda1 = True


while True:

    Enemy1.destroy()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
           pygame.quit()
           sys.exit()

    if InGame == True:
        Player.move()  
        Player.shoot(ventana)

    ventana.fill((205,69,159))

    if ronda1 == True:
       Enemy1.draw(ventana)
       Enemy1.movement()
       Enemy1.follow()



    Player.draw(ventana)
    Player.drawShoot(ventana)


    pygame.display.update()


Game()
```

`zombieN1` se mueve constantemente hasta la izquierda como se ve en su `def movement()`. Quiero que cuando `zombieN1` colisione con el `disparo(rectS)` de `Snake`, `zombieN1` se destruya. ¿Alguno de ustedes podría ayudarme? Si necesitan mas información o que me explique mejor díganme. Uso Python 3.6.3.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Existen métodos de la clase `pygame.sprite` pensados para hacer justo eso, detectar colisiones y destruir los sprites que lo hacen. Tanto [`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) como [`pygame.sprite.groupcollide`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.groupcollide) permiten hacer esto. La primera permite detectar la colisión de un sprite con un grupo de sprites, la segunda detecta colisiones entre dos grupos.

Personalmente haría dos cambios en tu código, sobretodo si pretendes poder tener múltiples "balas" y múltiples "zombies" a la vez en la pantalla:

- Tu sprite "disparo" debería tener su propia clase. Los videojuegos son una de la razones de peso por las que existe la POO. Tener una clase propia te va a permitir (además de encapsular mucho mejor el código) manejar distinto número de disparos y de distintos tipo con mucha facilidad si lo requieres, así como manejar colisiones y otros eventos con mucha más facilidad.
- Usar grupos de sprites (`pygame.sprite.Group()`). Si creas grupos para almacenar todos los sprites que tengan las misma características (enemigos, disparos, etc) se facilita mucho la tarea de detectar colisiones gracias a los métodos antes señalados.

He terminado cambiando bastantes cosas, pero un ejemplo de lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint


ancho = 1280
alto = 720


class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/cazador1 der.png") 
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()        
        self.rect.centerx = 80
        self.rect.centery = 80

        self.vel = 1
        self.vidas = 3
        self.viviendo = True

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 

        if keys[K_DOWN]: 
           self.rect.y += self.vel 
           if self.rect.bottom > 720:
              self.rect.bottom = 720 

        if keys[K_UP]: 
           self.rect.y -= self.vel 
           if self.rect.top < 0:
              self.rect.top = 0  

        if keys[K_RIGHT]: 
           self.rect.x += self.vel
           if self.rect.right > 1280:
              self.rect.right = 1280     

        if keys[K_LEFT]: 
           self.rect.x -= self.vel 
           if self.rect.left < 0:
              self.rect.left = 0     

        if keys[K_SPACE] and not bullets:         
            bullet = Bullet(self.rect.right, self.rect.centery)
            all_sprites.add(bullet)
            bullets.add(bullet)         


class ZombieN1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/zombie1 izq.png")      
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.s = Snake()
        self.y = self.s.rect.top 
        self.x = randint(1016,1280)

        self.rect.top = self.y
        self.rect.right = self.x 
        self.vel = 1

    def update(self):
        self.rect.left = self.rect.left - self.vel


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/disparo1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centery = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.vel = 3

    def update(self):
        self.rect.right += self.vel 
        # Destruir cuando se salga de la ventana (lado derecho)
        if self.rect.right > 1280:    
            self.kill()        

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombies = pygame.sprite.Group()

def Game():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,25) 

    ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho, alto))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

    player = Snake()
    enemy1 = ZombieN1()
    all_sprites.add(enemy1)
    zombies.add(enemy1)
    all_sprites.add(player)

    BG = pygame.image.load("sprites/fondo.png")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()

        # Comprobamos si algún disparo colisiona con algún enemigo
        ## En caso afirmativo se destruyen ambos
        pygame.sprite.groupcollide(zombies, bullets, True, True)

        # Actualizamos todos los sprites del juego
        all_sprites.update()
        ventana.fill((205,69,159))
        # Dibujamos todos los sprites
        all_sprites.draw(ventana)
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

Game()
```

He usado `groupcollide` ya que por norma general se tiene varios enemigos y varios disparos a la vez:

```
pygame.sprite.groupcollide(zombies, bullets, True, True)
```

Los dos primeros argumentos son los dos grupos de sprites que debe vigilar en busca de colisiones, los dos argumentos siguientes indican si cuando uno de cada grupo colisionen debe destruirlos.

Ten en cuenta que `groupcollide` retorna un diccionario con las colisiones que detecte, el cual puedes usar para manejarlas:

```
colisiones = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(zombies, bullets, True, True)
```

El diccionario `colisiones` será de la forma:

```
 {<zombieN1 sprite(in 0 groups)>: [<Bullet sprite(in 0 groups)>]}
```

pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite1, sprite2)

---

Si solo vas a tener un enemigo y un disparo y no vas a usar grupos puedes usar algo como:

```
if pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite_disparo, sprite_enemigo):
     # Lo que quieras hacer, como destruir (sprite_enemigo.kill())
```

La misma idea puedes aplicar con tu personaje y los enemigos para detectar las colisiones.

Con el código anterior y unos sprite dignos de un maestro de Blender XD tenemos lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

**Edición:**

Si quieres que un enemigo tenga varias vidas solo debes crear ese atributo en su clase, luego iterar sobre el diccionario que retorna `groupcollide` y a cada zombie restarle una vida, llamando a su método `kill` cuando su atributo vida sea menor o igual a 0.

Una opción muy flexible es que definas un atributo `health`en la clase del enemigo y que sea un entero. Según causes daño le restas una determinada cantidad de vida, haciendo que se destruya cuando llegue a cero. La gracia de esto es que puedes usar diferentes "armas" que causen diferente daño.

Te dejo un ejemplo usando esta idea, en este caso la salud será de 300 y por cada bala pierde 100. El daño de la bala está definido en el atributo `damage` de su clase. Podrías tener otro tipo de "bala" que causara 50 de daño, otra 10, etc. Uso una `property` junto a un `setter` para que sea el propio objeto el que se destruya cuando su vida llegue a cero, la programación orientada a objetos es muy bonita para estas cosas :)

- En tu clase `Bullet` añadir en el `__init__` el atributo `self.damage = 100`
- En clase `ZombieN1` añadir el atributo `self._health = 300` en su `__init__` y luego definimos la *property* `health` y el *setter*:

  ```
  @property
  def health(self):
      return self._health

  @health.setter
  def health(self, value):
      self._health = value
      if self._health <= 0:
          self.kill()
  ```
- Y por último, en el `while True` cambiar la linea con el `groupcollide` por:

  ```
  # Comprobamos si algún disparo colisiona con algún enemigo
  ## En caso afirmativo se destruye la bala y se le resta el daño de esta al zombie
  colls = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(zombies, bullets, False, True)
  for zombie, bullets_ in colls.items():
      zombie.health -= sum(bullet.damage for bullet in bullets_)
  ```

Quedaría todo así:

```
import pygame,sys
from pygame.locals import *
from random import randint


ancho = 1280
alto = 720


class Snake(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/cazador1 der.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = 80
        self.rect.centery = 80

        self.vel = 1
        self.vidas = 3
        self.viviendo = True

    def update(self):
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_DOWN]:
           self.rect.y += self.vel
           if self.rect.bottom > 720:
              self.rect.bottom = 720

        if keys[K_UP]:
           self.rect.y -= self.vel
           if self.rect.top < 0:
              self.rect.top = 0

        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
           self.rect.x += self.vel
           if self.rect.right > 1280:
              self.rect.right = 1280

        if keys[K_LEFT]:
           self.rect.x -= self.vel
           if self.rect.left < 0:
              self.rect.left = 0

        if keys[K_SPACE] and not bullets:
            bullet = Bullet(self.rect.right, self.rect.centery)
            all_sprites.add(bullet)
            bullets.add(bullet)


class ZombieN1(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/zombie1 izq.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.s = Snake()
        self.y = self.s.rect.top
        self.x = randint(1016,1280)

        self.rect.top = self.y
        self.rect.right = self.x
        self.vel = 1
        self._health = 300

    def update(self):
        self.rect.left = self.rect.left - self.vel

    @property
    def health(self):
        return self._health

    @health.setter
    def health(self, value):
        self._health = value
        if self._health <= 0:
            self.kill()

class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("sprites/disparo1.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centery = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.vel = 3
        self.damage = 100

    def update(self):
        self.rect.right += self.vel
        # Destruir cuando se salga de la ventana (lado derecho)
        if self.rect.right > 1280:
            self.kill()

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
bullets = pygame.sprite.Group()
zombies = pygame.sprite.Group()

def Game():
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(1,25)

    ventana = pygame.display.set_mode((ancho, alto))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

    player = Snake()
    enemy1 = ZombieN1()
    all_sprites.add(enemy1)
    zombies.add(enemy1)
    all_sprites.add(player)

    BG = pygame.image.load("sprites/fondo.png")

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
               pygame.quit()
               sys.exit()

        # Comprobamos si algún disparo colisiona con algún enemigo
        ## En caso afirmativo se destruye la bala y se le resta el daño de esta al zombie
        colls = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(zombies, bullets, False, True)
        for zombie, bullets_ in colls.items():
            zombie.health -= sum(bullet.damage for bullet in bullets_)

        # Actualizamos todos los sprites del juego
        all_sprites.update()
        ventana.fill((205,69,159))
        # Dibujamos todos los sprites
        all_sprites.draw(ventana)
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

Game()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias. Veo que eres bastante experimentado con esto podrias recomendarme algun manual o algo?