# Eliminar un rectángulo cuando otro objeto choca contra el mismo en pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Esta es mi primera publicación en el foro ^^ 
Estoy aprendiendo pygame y se me ocurrió crear el juego de arkanoid. Bien pues mi problema está en el momento en que la bola choca contra un bloque, rebota pero no consigo hacer desaparecer dicho bloque.

```
import pygame
import sys


pygame.init()

screen = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen)
pygame.display.set_caption("El juego de romper los bloques que no se como se llama :)")

#barra
x = 340
y = 500
width = 100
height = 10
vel = 1

#Pelota
width_ball = 800
height_ball = 600
ball = pygame.image.load("ball.png")
ball_rect = ball.get_rect()
ball_vel = [1,1]

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(2)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False


    #Movimiento barra
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel - 1:
        x -= vel

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 800 - width:
        x += vel

    #Pelota

    ball_rect = ball_rect.move(ball_vel)
    if ball_rect.left < 0 or ball_rect.right > width_ball:
        ball_vel[0] = -ball_vel[0]
    if ball_rect.top < 0 or ball_rect.bottom > height_ball:
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]

    #barra
    barra = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))

    if ball_rect.colliderect(barra):
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)

    #Rectangulos
    rect1 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 115, 179), (80, 50, 100, 25))
    rect2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 115, 179), (190, 50, 100, 25))
    rect3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 115, 179), (300, 50, 100, 25))
    rect4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 115, 179), (410, 50, 100, 25))
    rect5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 115, 179), (520, 50, 100, 25))
    rect6 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 115, 179), (630, 50, 100, 25))
    #Rectangulos 2
    rect1_2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (142, 0, 0), (135, 85, 100, 25))
    rect2_2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (142, 0, 0), (245, 85, 100, 25))
    rect3_2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (142, 0, 0), (355, 85, 100, 25))
    rect4_2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (142, 0, 0), (465, 85, 100, 25))
    rect5_2 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (142, 0, 0), (575, 85, 100, 25))
    #Rectangulos 3
    rect1_3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (10, 65, 87), (80, 120, 100, 25))
    rect2_3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (10, 65, 87), (190, 120, 100, 25))
    rect3_3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (10, 65, 87), (300, 120, 100, 25))
    rect4_3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (10, 65, 87), (410, 120, 100, 25))
    rect5_3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (10, 65, 87), (520, 120, 100, 25))
    rect6_3 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (10, 65, 87), (630, 120, 100, 25))
    #Rectangulos 4
    rect1_4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (199, 147, 0), (135, 155, 100, 25))
    rect2_4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (199, 147, 0), (245, 155, 100, 25))
    rect3_4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (199, 147, 0), (355, 155, 100, 25))
    rect4_4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (199, 147, 0), (465, 155, 100, 25))
    rect5_4 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (199, 147, 0), (575, 155, 100, 25))
    #Rectangulos 5
    rect1_5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 228, 179), (80, 190, 100, 25))
    rect2_5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 228, 179), (190, 190, 100, 25))
    rect3_5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 228, 179), (300, 190, 100, 25))
    rect4_5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 228, 179), (410, 190, 100, 25))
    rect5_5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 228, 179), (520, 190, 100, 25))
    rect6_5 = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 228, 179), (630, 190, 100, 25))
    #empiezan los rebotes con los recángulos :)
    if ball_rect.colliderect(rect1_5):
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]
        rect1_5.fill(255,255,255)
    elif ball_rect.colliderect(rect2_5):
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]
        rect2_5.fill(255,255,255)
    elif ball_rect.colliderect(rect3_5):
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]
        rect3_5.fill(255,255,255)
    elif ball_rect.colliderect(rect4_5):
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]
        rect4_5.fill(255,255,255)
    elif ball_rect.colliderect(rect5_5):
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]
        rect5_5.fill(255,255,255)
    elif ball_rect.colliderect(rect6_5):
        ball_vel[1] = -ball_vel[1]
        rect6_5.fill(255,255,255)

    #Barra
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

También agradecería posibles consejos de mejora de aplicación y el código; por ejemplo:tengo otro problema cuando se ejecuta el juego, la bola siempre aparece en el  mismo lugar y no se me ocurre cómo podría hacer que empezase en otro sitio. 
Por supuesto no está acabado ni lo más mínimo. 
Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, no puedes aplicar `fill` sobre una instancia de `pygame.Rect`, `fill` es un método propio de `pygame.Surface`. `Rect` solo representa las coordenadas de un rectángulo, no es algo sobre lo que se pueda dibujar.

Dicho esto, en vez de usar un condicional por cada rectángulo, es mucho más simple y escalable si almacenas en algún iterable la información de cada uno (`Rect` y color). En cada iteración del ciclo principal simplemente iteras sobre el contenedor con los rectángulos, por cada uno compruebas si la bola colisiona, si lo hace lo eliminas y si no lo dibujas.

Por ejemplo, usando una lista:

```
import sys
import pygame


# Constantes iniciales
FPS = 60
SCREEN_SIZE = 800, 600
BALL_SIZE = 30, 30
BAR_SIZE = 100, 10
SCREEN_CENTER = SCREEN_SIZE[0] // 2, SCREEN_SIZE[1] // 2
COLOR1 = (255, 115, 179)
COLOR2 = (142, 0, 0)
COLOR3 = (10, 65, 87)
COLOR4 = (199, 147, 0)
COLOR5 = (0, 228, 179)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

# Instanciamos la ventana
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN_SIZE)
pygame.display.set_caption(
    "El juego de romper los bloques que no se como se llama :)"
    )

# Barra
bar_rect = pygame.Rect(SCREEN_CENTER[0] - BAR_SIZE[0] // 2, 500, *BAR_SIZE)
bar_vel = 5

# Pelota
ball = pygame.image.load("/home/fjsevilla/Escritorio//ball.png")
ball = pygame.transform.scale(ball, BALL_SIZE)
ball_rect = ball.get_rect().move(
    bar_rect.centerx - BALL_SIZE[0] // 2,
    bar_rect.top - BALL_SIZE[1]
)
ball_vel = [-3, -3]

# Rectangulos
rects = [(COLOR1, pygame.Rect(80, 50, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR1, pygame.Rect(190, 50, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR1, pygame.Rect(300, 50, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR1, pygame.Rect(410, 50, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR1, pygame.Rect(520, 50, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR1, pygame.Rect(630, 50, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR2, pygame.Rect(135, 85, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR2, pygame.Rect(245, 85, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR2, pygame.Rect(355, 85, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR2, pygame.Rect(465, 85, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR2, pygame.Rect(575, 85, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR3, pygame.Rect(80, 120, 100, 25)), 
         (COLOR3, pygame.Rect(190, 120, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR3, pygame.Rect(300, 120, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR3, pygame.Rect(410, 120, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR3, pygame.Rect(520, 120, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR3, pygame.Rect(630, 120, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR4, pygame.Rect(135, 155, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR4, pygame.Rect(245, 155, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR4, pygame.Rect(355, 155, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR4, pygame.Rect(465, 155, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR4, pygame.Rect(575, 155, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR5, pygame.Rect(80, 190, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR5, pygame.Rect(190, 190, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR5, pygame.Rect(300, 190, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR5, pygame.Rect(410, 190, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR5, pygame.Rect(520, 190, 100, 25)),
         (COLOR5, pygame.Rect(630, 190, 100, 25))
         ]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    # Movimiento barra
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and bar_rect.left > 0:
        bar_rect.left -= bar_vel
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and bar_rect.right < SCREEN_SIZE[0]:
        bar_rect.right += bar_vel

    # Colisiones de pelota
    if ball_rect.left < 0 or ball_rect.right > SCREEN_SIZE[0]:
        ball_vel[0] *= -1
    elif ball_rect.top < 0 or ball_rect.bottom > SCREEN_SIZE[1]:
        ball_vel[1] *= -1
    elif ball_rect.colliderect(bar_rect):
        ball_vel[1] *= -1

    # Movemos la pelota
    ball_rect = ball_rect.move(ball_vel)

    # Booramos contendio de pantalla
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # Dibujado de la barra
    barra = pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, bar_rect)

    # Dibujado de los rectángulos
    del_recs = []
    for i, rectangle in enumerate(rects):
        color, rect = rectangle
        if not ball_rect.colliderect(rect):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect)
        else:
            del_recs.append(i)
            ball_vel[1] *= -1

    # Eliminamos los rectángulos colisionados
    for n, i in enumerate(del_recs):
        del rects[i - n]

    # Dibujado de la pelota
    screen.blit(ball, ball_rect)

    # Actualización de la pantalla
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Espera necesaria hasta nueva iteración del mainloop
    clock.tick_busy_loop(FPS)

pygame.quit()
```

Para reproducirlo solo es necesario el sprite de la pelotita, en mi caso he usado éste:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He modificado más cosas, como el uso de  `pygame.Clock.tick_busy_loop` para estabilizar de forma básica los FPS y he renombrado varias variables para que los nombres sean algo más explícitos acorde a lo que representan.

Para cambiar la posición original de la bola, basta con que obtengas la recta de la misma y uses el método `move` de la misma. En  encima de la barra centrada, pero puedes colocarla donde desees.

Esto no entra dentro de la pregunta y sería extenderse mucho, pero el sistema de colisiones es imperfecto y muy simplificado dado que no se tiene en cuenta si la colisión se produce en un lateral o en la parte superior/inferior del rectángulo.

Si usas POO y haces uso de los Sprites y grupos la tarea de detectar colisiones y del dibujado se pude simplificar, tienes un ejemplo en:

- [Detectar y destruir objetos que colisionan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/128691/detectar-y-destruir-objetos-que-colisionan/128717#128717)

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias por tu ayuda, me ha sido de gran utilidad!! ^.^